# Copy-on-modify behaviour different between `c(1L, 2L, 3L)` and `1:3`

Tags: r

I'm reading [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) by Hadley Wickham, trying to solve [exercise 2](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#exercises-1) from section 2.3.6 about copy-on-modify:

> Explain why `tracemem()` shows two copies when you run this code. Hint: carefully look at the difference between this code and the code shown earlier in the section.
>
> ```
> x <- c(1L, 2L, 3L)
> tracemem(x)
>
> x[[3]] <- 4
> ```

(The previous code changed one element in a list of doubles to another double, yielding only one copy.)

In the [Advanced R Solutions](https://advanced-r-solutions.rbind.io/) by Grosser and Bumann [they explain](https://advanced-r-solutions.rbind.io/names-and-values.html#copy-on-modify) that the second copy is due to type coercion, from integer to double. They do not define `x` as `c(1L, 2L, 3L)`, but use `x <- 1:3`, which I thought was equivalent (comparing them using `identical` also returns `TRUE`). However, running the above code (on my end) only yields one copy, but running the following code yields two copies:

```
x <- 1:3
tracemem(x)

x[[3]] <- 4
```

Running this code also yields two copies:

```
x <- c(1L, 2L, 3L)
typeof(x)
tracemem(x)

x[[3]] <- 4
```

For example replacing `typeof` with `class` only yields one copy, but replacing it with `mode` or `pryr::otype` yields two copies. But simply printing `x` out instead yields one copy.

So what is the difference between `c(1L, 2L, 3L)` and `1:3`, and why do calling some but not all of the above functions alter the behaviour?

I get the same behaviour running the code from PowerShell using `Rterm` and in the console in RStudio.

Comment: Interesting, I even see different behaviors if I run the lines separately, so `x <- c(1L, 2L, 3L); tracemem(x); x[[3]] <- 4` shows 1 copy but `x <- c(1L, 2L, 3L); tracemem(x)` -> Enter -> `x[[3]] <- 4` shows 2.

Comment: I think this might be related to the recent addition of ALTREP, which has performance benefits in lots of other contexts, but means that vectors like `1:3` are stored in a different "compact" form that reference only their start/end values.

Comment: Yes, that probably explains that one, for the others I don't know.

Comment: tbh, I'm a little thrown by the fact that I'm getting `NAM(3)` on all these objects. This is well outside my area of expertise, but I wonder if R has also updated it's NAMED system somehow that I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in @brodieg's blog at https://www.brodieg.com/2019/02/18/an-unofficial-reference-for-internal-inspect/#fn4

Rather than use tracemem, go deeper with `.Internal(inspect(x))`

```
x <- c(1L, 6L, 10L)
.Internal(inspect(x))
#> @7fc0397e0f88 13 INTSXP g0c2 [NAM(1)] (len=3, tl=0) 1,6,10
x <- c(1L, 6L, 10L)
typeof(x)
.Internal(inspect(x))
#> @7fc0397e0f08 13 INTSXP g0c2 [NAM(7)] (len=3, tl=0) 1,6,10
```

The return value of `.Internal(inspect(x))` is a pile of info, but the important bit is NAM. NAM is the reference counter, a way to determine how many R objects are pointing to the same underlying thing. Here `typeof()` incremented it. `typeof()` is a closure, and the “NAM” value on arguments to closures are always incremented.

Per @brodieg x won't always be copied when a new value is assigned to an element, but may when the NAM reference counting heuristic suggests there could be more than one reference to the object.

I couldn't find any info on references and `:`, but an object created with it automatically has a reference count > 1

```
x <- 1:3
.Internal(inspect(x))
#> @7fc03bad6388 13 INTSXP g0c0 [NAM(7)]  1 : 3 (compact)
```

So for the original situation with `x <- c(1L, 6L, 10L)`, the reference count is only 1, and the R heuristics don't trigger a copy for the assignment, but do for the type coercion. That's why `tracemem` is only triggered once.